# Add grid lines to y-axis in NPOI bar chart

Tags: c#, npoi

I'd like to add horizontal grid lines to a bar chart (IChart) I created using NPOI. I can't find anything in the documentation about adding grid lines to a chart, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something. My code is shown below:

```
IDrawing drawing = sheet.CreateDrawingPatriarch();
IClientAnchor anchor = drawing.CreateAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, chartRow, 10, chartRow + 30);
IChart chart = drawing.CreateChart(anchor);
IBarChartData<string, double> data = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreateBarChartData<string, double>();
IChartAxis xAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.Bottom);
xAxis.MajorTickMark = AxisTickMark.None;
xAxis.MinorTickMark = AxisTickMark.None;
IValueAxis yAxis = chart.ChartAxisFactory.CreateValueAxis(AxisPosition.Left);
yAxis.MajorTickMark = AxisTickMark.Cross;
yAxis.MinorTickMark = AxisTickMark.None;
yAxis.Crosses = AxisCrosses.AutoZero;
yAxis.SetCrossBetween(AxisCrossBetween.Between);

IChartDataSource<string> xSource = DataSources.FromStringCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(chartRow + 1, lastRow, 0, 0));
IChartDataSource<double> ySource = DataSources.FromNumericCellRange(sheet, new CellRangeAddress(chartRow + 1, lastRow, 1, 1));
IBarChartSeries<string, double> series = data.AddSeries(xSource, ySource);
series.SetTitle("Matches By World-Check Category"); // This doesn't display for some reason
chart.Plot(data, xAxis, yAxis);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying minor and major gridlines for chart is not supported.

I would suggest to create a [ticket](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi/issues/new) for an enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the gridlines with something like this

```
chart.GetCTChart().plotArea.valAx[0].AddNewMajorGridlines(); // Alongside Y
chart.GetCTChart().plotArea.catAx[0].AddNewMajorGridlines(); // Alongside X
```